# How to make the Order by statement for Two fields in a single query and one field needs to DESC and one field needs to ASC using Mysql?

Tags: sql, mysql

I want to make a query that will give the result on order by using two columns.
I made  query like this.

```
select 
    el.*,
    lb.LabName,lb.LabType,
    lb.LabDescription
from encounterlab el
INNER JOIN
    labs lb
    ON 
    lb.LabType=el.LabType
where 
    PatientAcctNo=4 ORDER BY el.DataOfService,lb.LabName DESC
```

It gives the results.But My aim is IF in the DataOfService contain the same date I want to make the Order depending upon the LabName  and this should be ASC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can optionally specify the order for each single field in the order by statement

```
ORDER BY field1 DESC, field2 ASC
```

Comment: Thanks zolex.Working Fine.One More doubt like this we can Order n number of columns right?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, your current query orders in the opposite direction that you want (for both columns!). Ordering ascending (`ASC`) is implicit, and you always have a direction per column you're ordering by. So your example:

```
ORDER BY el.DataOfService,lb.LabName DESC
```

Is the same as:

```
ORDER BY el.DataOfService ASC, lb.LabName DESC
```

So what you want is this:

```
ORDER BY el.DataOfService DESC, lb.LabName
```